# How to send consecutive images to android phone from computer

Tags: java, android, javax.imageio, live-streaming

I am working on a project. It is about capturing photos from the PC and monitoring them on an Android phone screen.

I use `JpegEncoder` or `ImageIO` classes from the PC side and on the Android side I use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` method. When I send one image it works well but I need to send images continuously (2 or 3 images per second). It does not work in a while loop.

In logchat view it shows this error message until I close the Android application:

```
 SkImageDecoder : Factory returned null
```

I think the problem is about cursor position in stream from `ImageIO` code side the `ImageIO.write(img,"jpg",ostream)` methot flushes stream  after every sent but Android side
BitmapFactory.decodeBitmap() does not flush after  every reading so the error is  `SkImageDecoder returned null`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question, you may find an answer for yourself too

[BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is) returns null for non null InputStream on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940487/bitmapfactory-decodestreaminputstream-is-returns-null-for-non-null-inputstream)

Comment: as well as i understood it is not about my problem because i can load image succesfully when i sent only one Image so it looks there is no problem while reading stream bytes so dont need to  skip method brother. Thanks for advice