# Monodroid BitmapFactory.DecodeFileDescriptor Bitmap always null

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

I use the following method to prevend a outofmemory exception, but the Bitmap ist always null. Has anybody an idea?

```
public Bitmap readBitmap(Android.Net.Uri selectedImage) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.InSampleSize = 9;
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
        try {
            fileDescriptor =  this.ContentResolver.OpenAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage,"r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message, ToastLength.Long);
        }
        finally{
            try {
                bm =  BitmapFactory.DecodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.FileDescriptor, null, options);
                fileDescriptor.Close();
            } catch (IOException) {
            }
        }
        return bm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is another bug of Google. Solution is to do this:

```
bm =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor));
```

Instead of

```
bm =  BitmapFactory.DecodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.FileDescriptor, null, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapFactory.DecodeFileDescriptor` must be throwing an exception if bm is null.

Answer (score 0):

On your catch, try modifying like this

```
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.v ("Message", ""+e.message);
        }
```

So you could see whats the error that it returns to null

Comment: android.resource://My.Paketname/drawable/tabbar is my uri

My.Paketname is of course the correct name

Comment: then refer on my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559481/downloaded-image-can-not-be-displayed/12559586#12559586

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Uri is incorect and `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. But you can't see this because you are missing the `show()` method of the Toast in the catch clause.

Should be like this:

```
 Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message, ToastLength.Long).show();
```

Comment: hm okay, I don't know what could be wrong with my uri android.resource://My.Paketname/drawable/tabbar

Comment: Uri is correct, I checked this, I could set an imageview with this uri

Comment: Are you sure there insn't any exception thrown? Try to step through the program in debug mode and see the flow.

Comment: I tried to write the exception to the console, but there isn't one.
Maybe the only hint is SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null in my Application Output

Comment: Could be. But I can't say that for sure.