# Android BitmapFactory can't decode inputstream

Tags: android, inputstream, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to get image from the webserver like this:

```
@Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            stream = connection.getInputStream();
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return stream;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            Bitmap avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
            user.avatar = avatar;
            if (user.avatar != null)
                imgAvatar.setImageBitmap(user.avatar);
            buf.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But my `Bitmap avatar` is null. I've been looking through received InputStream via debugger, it holds right url, and it has fields `httpEngine/responseBodyIn/bytesRemaining` which is holding number of bytes equals to the image size. Image is in the .png format.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5941493/1443981

Comment: when facing bitmap issu i always take a look here https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it using Apache HttpClient instead of HttpUrlConnection:

```
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        InputStream instream = null;

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(new URL(strings[0]).toURI());
            response = client.execute(request);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                return null;
            }
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
            instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

            return instream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if (instream != null) {
                try {
                    instream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
        Bitmap avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        if (avatar != null) {
            user.avatar = avatar;
            imgAvatar.setImageBitmap(avatar);
        }
    }
```