# Bitmap decode stream from URL return nulled (SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null)

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream

We try to decode image stream to Bitmap but it return nulled.

from this Code

```
URL aURL = new URL(url);
URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 768, 1280);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, options);
bis.close();
is.close();
```

We get Log cat

```
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

but when we using only

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
```

it's work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an issue similar to this recently.  There is an issue when decoding a `InputStream` in two passes (first for the image bounds, then the actual decoding), where the `InputStream` isn't reset after the first pass - which was causing the error in my case.  To fix this, I just reset the `InputStream` after the first pass by closing the original stream that was used to get the image bounds, then reopening a new stream before doing the actual `Bitmap` decoding.

This fixed the problem in my situation, but this is a fairly common issue.  If doing the above doesn't work - it might be worth looking into [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066) Google Code issue, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940487/bitmapfactory-decodestreaminputstream-is-returns-null-for-non-null-inputstream) SO post about using BufferedHttpEntities.

Comment: Can you show code, How to reopening new stream? Thanks

Comment: @ipOP : you need to either do the request twice or save the image to cache (in memory or on disk) before using it.

Comment: BufferedHttpEntities is deprecated so now what ?

Answer (score 0):

I try to add below code before set `inJustDecodeBounds` to `FALSE`

```
//... calculateInSampleSize
is.close();
conn = aURL.openConnection();
conn.connect();
is = conn.getInputStream();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
```

It's work correctly but I'm not sure this is bestway to solve my problem