# Application behaviour changed with Android 4.1(Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have an application consist of ListView and each row open activity inside the activity there is button when pressd open another activity which is the gallery ,

I used large sized high resolution images in `res -> drawable` , then test it in two devices :

**First one** is galaxy pocket duos running ginger bread 2.3.6 , its 
working ok but slow in scrolling the list but all app function working .

**second one**  is  galaxy s 3 running Jelly 
Bean 4.1.2 and ( used large sized high resolution images in res drawable ), app open show the list but freezed you cant 
scroll the list and if you try to scroll it its getting out app (**app closed**) return to mobile home screen without force close ,

then I changed the image with small sized low resolution images its worked fine in galaxy s3 .

i expect the opposite to freeze on galaxy pocket duos rather than galaxy s3 because its low specification than galaxy s3 .

Any solutions to problem will be appreciated.

My manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.tsn.dr"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="8"
   android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens 
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: jelly man not gelly :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is loading large and many images

So your app scrolling problem and app crash some time..

Use **Lazzy Loading** or use **getview method in your custom adapter**...

below link are useful to you for lazzy loading..

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

[Android: lazy loading in Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181728/android-lazy-loading-in-gallery)

Comment: would you please check post again , i updated with more explanation, thanks

Comment: ListView and each row open activity inside the activity there is button when pressd open another activity which is the gallery . another point :i expect the opposite to freeze on galaxy pocket duos rather than galaxy s3 because its low specification than galaxy s3 .